# Any notification when user opt out adid track

Tags: android

"Now, when users opt out of ad tracking, Google zeros out their ID and notifies developers and ad tech companies to delete that information in their backend systems."

It is in this document, [https://www.adexchanger.com/privacy/android-gets-its-own-privacy-sandbox-and-goodbye-google-ad-id-in-two-years-maybe/#:~:text=Previously%2C%20people%20were%20still%20associated,information%20in%20their%20backend%20systems](https://www.adexchanger.com/privacy/android-gets-its-own-privacy-sandbox-and-goodbye-google-ad-id-in-two-years-maybe/#:%7E:text=Previously%2C%20people%20were%20still%20associated,information%20in%20their%20backend%20systems).

How does my app get the notification when user Opt Out the track?